# When to invalidate Twitter API bearer access_token?

Tags: java, twitter, oauth

I followed the instructions here (https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/application-only) for obtaining an access_token to make calls against the Twitter API. I can get the access_token via curl. However I started thinking about the access token. I know that the access_token does not expire until it is invalidated. But what would normally happens to the access_token after the call is made to the API in the real world? Should it be invalidated after each call or is the client application expected to store it in a database or something? I am building a little demo application so am thinking of just writing it to a file?